# Do I need to keep bootstrap.js in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel

When I created my Laravel project, there's a file called `bootstrap.js` in `resources/js`. I'm not using Vue or any JS frameworks except JQuery, and when I'm running `npm run dev`, it compiles it into an `app.js` file that I'm not using.

It's not bootstrap 4 bootstrap, it's some file with Axios and CSRF tokens - do I need to include this, or can I safely delete it so that I can compile individual JS files using Mix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use it at all it's just contains some default setting for users to be more convenient you can use it if you are using jquery just keep the things that you want like jquery or csrf token or remove the entire js folder